# Problem to build NDK with C++ in Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Currently I am working with the Android NDK and JNI. I am trying to build a C++ code with NDK.

But I got the following errors:

```
E:/Android/Tranining_workspace/BackUpMigrant/jni/ReadBackupArc5/ReadBackupArc5.cpp:10:19: error: fstream: No such file or directory
E:/Android/Tranining_workspace/BackUpMigrant/jni/ReadBackupArc5/ReadBackupArc5.cpp:20: error: 'ifstream' does not name a type
E:/Android/Tranining_workspace/BackUpMigrant/jni/ReadBackupArc5/ReadBackupArc5.cpp:21: error: 'ofstream' does not name a type
E:/Android/Tranining_workspace/BackUpMigrant/jni/ReadBackupArc5/ReadBackupArc5.cpp:22: error: 'ofstream' does not name a type
E:/Android/Tranining_workspace/BackUpMigrant/jni/ReadBackupArc5/ReadBackupArc5.cpp:34: error: 'string' was not declared in this scope
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just encountered the same problem. Seems the STL is not automatically included in NDK projects by default. That also means `iostream`, `fstream`, `string` etc can't be used straight away. To enable them, you'll need to modify your `Application.mk` file. If you don't have one (it's in the `<project>/jni` directory), then just create a new, blank one. Add the line:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

Also, also remember to include `using namespace std;` or equivalent, along with the usual `#include <iostream>` etc.

Comment: stl i am getting "error: fstream: No such file or directory"
do u have an othet suggestion over this..

Comment: Can you paste the `#include` line that includes `fstream` for me. Also, which version of the SDK and JNI do you have? The newest SDK often doesn't update compiles. Also try deleting everything in the `bin` directory of your project and recompile.

Comment: i got solution for this problem..that is because of Android not support STL lib .. for support u just make an Application.mk file with single line contain "APP_STL := stlport_static"... that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember your:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

definitions at the top of the file?

("using namespace std" isn't always a good idea, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: Still it is not working. I think ndk could not find the iostream file. This file is available in the gnu-libstdc++ directory of the android NDK folder. I dont know how to connect with the C++ with libstdc++